# How to prove a distribution function and then find the probability mass function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given $X_1, X_2,... ,X_n$ be independent variables, each having a uniform distribution over (0,1). Let M = maximum
$(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$. *Show that the distribution function of M is given by* $$F_M (x) = x^n, 0 \leq x \leq 1$$
*What is the probability density function of M?*

Solution: 
Having $X_1, X_2,... ,X_n$ be independent variables, each having a uniform distribution over (0,1) implies $P(X_i < x) = x$ **Why this implication?**

$$P(X_1 < x, X_2 < x, X_3 < x,...) = P(X_1 < x ) P(X_2 < x)P(X_3 < x)...$$
Let M = maximum
$(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$. To find the distributions function of M calculate P(M < x)

$$F_M (x) = P(M < x )$$
$$ = P(maximum(X_1,X_2,...,X_n) < x )$$
$$ = P(X_1 < x, X_2 < x,...,X_n < x )$$
$$ = P(X_1 < x)P( X_2 < x)...P(X_n < x )$$
$$ = x.x...x (n times)$$
$$ = x^n$$

Since, $X_i$ lies between 0 and 1, and maximum of $X_i'$s lies between 0 and 1. **How do you know that the maximum also lies between 0 and 1?**
So,
$$F_M (x) = x^n, 0 \leq x \leq 1$$

The probability density function of M is $f_M(x)$.
$$f_M(x) = \dfrac{d}{dx}(F_M(x))$$
$$= \dfrac{d}{dx}(x^n)$$
$$= nx^n-1$$

**Why do we derivate $F_M(x)$ to get the probability density function of M?**

Comment: Some of your questions are a little odd.  For example you are asking why the derivative of the cumulative distribution function is the probability density function.  How would you define the density function?  You also ask why the maximum and minimum of a set of numbers between $0$ and $1$ are also between $0$ and $1$.  Do you want a formal analytical answer or an intuitive answer?

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, by definition, the maximum of a discrete finite set must be one of the members of the set.  Since all members are between 0 and 1, so must the maximum lie in that interval.

For question 2, as you noted $F_M(x)$ was relatively easy to derive.  Deriving $f_M(x)$ directly is much more difficult.